# Global utility functions in react? How to implement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to use a **"global function"** for the lack of a better word in many of my components, like 80% or more. This function is sort of a repository of messages translated to languages, so I would pass it for example `SM(1245, 'eng')` and it is suppose to return the message on English.

```
function SM(messageID, language){
    return languageMap.get(language).get(messageID);
}
```

The function pretty much acts like a getter for a map of maps, however, the data that is used to populate these maps is on the server.

If i understand it correctly, exporting the function from a file and then importing it into every component would "re-run" the function's script file multiple times, resulting in multiple server calls to get the data, which I'd like to avoid as to not DDOS my server when many users start using many components.

How do I go about this?

**EDIT:** I also thought of just making it a part of my App.js main component class but then i'd have to pass it down through props for long chains and i really would like to avoid that.

**EDIT 2:** Tried what was suggested in the comments, to add a simple .js file to the Index.html the normal way, define a function there and use it wherever I need it, the good old fashioned way. Managed to do that but the issues is a function added this way is not accesible at "complie time" for React app, or rather I cannot use it when evaluate .jsx expressions.

**Is there really no simple way to make a file which will be used for utility functions but will have data and not get called for every component, nor passed through long chain of props.?**

Comment: Are you working with Redux?

Comment: @FK82 Plan is to do so in the future but as it stands now no. Though do post what you have on your mind. (Also I edited the OP)

Comment: Why not use a library like https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl and have the translations as part of the component? The naive way I'm using for global functions is global.myFunction= function(... to get them in the global scope

Comment: you can achieve this by using Redux.

Comment: @rypskar I am new in all of this so I've no clue of the plethora of useful libraries that could solve the issue, I will look into the one you linked, though from what I just quickly skimmed through is not the issue I have. I have a repository of already preformated translations with grammar and all, I just need to serve them.

Comment: Having functions, classes or variables in another file and calling them from your react code should work, even if advanced react users will complain. Did you try having it in a file like Translations.js and include it in your HTML the old way and calling it from react code?

Comment: @rypskar I have but I cannot seem to get it to work. I've added the file to the `<head>` tag normally via `<script>` and I get an error message that says `Unexpected token <` coming from first line of the file, though when looked at, it points to the `<!DOCTYPE>` in the index, rather then the .js file. The file is just an IIFE that would add function to `global.myFunction` as you suggested, but it is never ran (i assume due to error). I added `console.log` to the very start of the IIFE, doesn't get fired so it is as if the file is not linked properly

Comment: Ok so to update anyone who is reading through the comments, I managed to import the file into the Index.html, but the functions in this file are not accessible at JSX compilation time... doesnt help then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, first of all, your assumption that multiple imports means multiple script executions is probably not true. I just tried it in Node JS and it seems like the re-imported modules were not ran again.

However, you can avoid multiple resource requests by caching the result in a **service** module. Here's a [simple example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-x9hz8x?file=index.js) on stackblitz. The service module only contains a function `getData` which returns either a promise issuing a request (which also caches the received data) or directly resolves to cached data (if they exist).

```
    // log this everytime the script is being executed
console.log('get-data.js module being executed');

// just an example
const resourceUrl = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bahamas10/css-color-names/master/css-color-names.json';

let cachedData = null;

const getData = () => {
    if (cachedData === null) {
        console.log('get-data: requesting data');
        return fetch(resourceUrl, {})
        .then(response => {
            cachedData = response.json();
            return cachedData;
        });
    } else {
        console.log('get-data: returning cached data');
        return Promise.resolve(cachedData);
    }
};

export { getData };
```

In the example, `getData` is getting executed in an interval every 5s. As you can see though from the log statements only the first call results in a request for fresh data; otherwise the cached data are being served.

I'm also importing `getData` twice (once in "index.js" and once in "header.js") but the console.log statement in "get-data.j" is only getting executed once. So it's very likely not being executed again after the first import.

---

If you want to get more fancy, there are a couple of other—arguably more complicated—ways to implement a "global" utility function. For example:

- [Redux middleware](https://redux.js.org/advanced/middleware), [Redux async middleware](https://redux.js.org/advanced/asyncflow)
- [Dependency injection](https://itnext.io/the-unstated-react-service-pattern-786ea6168d1d)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest keeping your messages in the context and create a component to retrieve the messages from the react context. You can also create a object with the "global" function and inject it with a HOC.

The way I do it is I have a  component that uses the react context to retrieve a message using the messages object and current locale to display it in the rendered output. I also created a HOC which injects some helper functions for retrieving messages for placeholders ect.

Comment: I am certain that if this was the case for something more complex or if I was more proficient, this would be an ideal solution, but as it stands now, it brings so many wrappers for something that I need to use very often that it makes the whole code look incredibly messy. +1 for a good suggestion and read, might use it sometimes somewhere else, not in this case though